# Spawn small Form in the Middle of another Form

Tags: c#, forms

I have one Form, from this i want to open another Form, that displays in the middle of the parent form. Therefor i used this code:

```
using (var form = new Login())
{
    var result = form.ShowDialog(this);
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(form.getClientID);
    }
}
```

In the Login-Form i set the StartPosition to CenterParent. If i call it like this it works, but i think the problem is the "this" here: `var result = form.ShowDialog(this);` but i don't know how i should tell it where to be the childform from otherwise.
My code in the Login-Form looks like this:

```
public string getClientID { get; set; }

public Login()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.getClientID = this.clientID.Text;
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    this.Close();
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
This is the error i get on `var result = form.ShowDialog(this)`:

> An Exception error of type "System.ArgumentException" has occurred in
>   System.Windows.Forms.dll. Additional Information: A circular control
>   reference has been issued. A control can not own itself or be
>   superordinate.

Comment: Unclear. It works or not? And if it works then what is the problem?

Comment: @Steve it works till, i click the button, then i get this error: "An Exception error of type "System.ArgumentException" has occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll.

Additional Information: A circular control reference has been issued. A control can not own itself or be superordinate."(translated from german into english) an dthe error pops up on this: "var result = form.ShowDialog(this);"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is actually very easy, remove the `this` and add this line at the start of the using statement.

```
form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
```

Comment: ye, this works without crashing now, but it's not centered. It gets displayed in the top left. I call it after InitializeComponent() in my Main Form. Do you have a fix for this aswell!? :)

Comment: Top left of the main form or window?

Comment: Because for me if I open it from the main form it opens perfectly in the middle. Also when would you like to call it? When it loads? when the user presses a button?

Comment: i fixed it on my own, thanks anyways for your solution! :)

Comment: Good to hear that you've fixed it!

Comment: @ZZ_James - If you've fixed it, please add an answer and tell what you did to fix it.  That way it may help somone else in the future.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I tried OP's code with my addition right after `InitializeComponent()` (this is where OP had it) and it did not work properly, I would imagine he moved this. But the answer to the question asked in the title was clearly my answer.